# R - Box Cox transformation on multiple regression

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, transformation

I have applied box cox transformation on multiple regression,

```
summary(powerTransform(cbind(MEDPRICE, MEDROOM, CRIME, SALES, INCOMEDEP, TIMESHOP) ~ 1, data = Glas_subset))
```

but I want to confirm two things in the analysis

1. Can we run the linear regression analysis with lambda value embedded in the model?

lamda.a <- -0.3; lamda.b <- -1; lamda.c <- -0.1; lamda.d <- 0.5 ; lamda.e <- 0.33

```
Glasgowlm_log4 <- (lm(log(MEDPRICE) ~ bcPower(MEDROOM, lamda.b)+ MEDROOM + bcPower(CRIME, lamda.c) + CRIME + bcPower(SALES, lamda.d) + SALES + TYPE +bcPower(INCOMEDEP, lamda.e)+ INCOMEDEP +log(TIMESHOP), data=Glas_subset))
```

2. do we have to add variable twice like "bcPower(MEDROOM, lamda.b)+ MEDROOM"?

Could someone verify whether the procedure for analysis is correct?

Thanks

Comment: What packages are you using? `bcPower` and `powerTransform` are not in default packages.

Comment: This might be a better fit for stats.stackexchange... seems like more of a stats question than a programming question.

Comment: I used "car" and "e1071" packages for bcpower and powertransform functions